# Error in For /F statement in Windows Batch Script

Tags: database, windows, batch-file, scripting, db2

I am trying to run a command in a batch script to parse to the fourth word of a line.

This command works fine on the command line but gives an error when run inside a script. The error states :

> **Skip was not expected at this time**

```
db2cmd -i -c FOR /F "usebackq skip=3 tokens=4" %%G IN ("aliasname.txt") DO DB2 UNCATALOG SYSTEM DATABASE %%G
```

Could you please check what might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: But this command is running fine in the same batch file : db2cmd -i -c FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`DB2 LIST SYSTEM ODBC DATA SOURCES`) DO DB2 UNCATALOG SYSTEM ODBC DATA SOURCE %%i

Comment: Is the prefix same for windows? I see an error that says the command is not recognized :(

Comment: I'm going to assume that, when the `For` command is passed to `db2cmd` it requires to be quoted appropriately. This looks like when passed, it is seeing the `=` character as problematic. You may need to pass the entire command in doublequotes, and probably escape internal ones at the same time.

Comment: Do I escape all the internal ones? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Aastha Dadal, please try it yourself with and without internal escapes and see what happens. I'd assume that the most likely escape method would be to use a backslash, i.e. **`\"`**, so it shouldn't take you more than a few seconds to try each method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different options, achieve the same result, depends on your style.

- omit the explicit `db2cmd -i -c` prefix for any Db2 CLP action and auto run the whole script under db2cmd . This has the advantage that it will run either in a CMD.EXE or DB2CMD.EXE window without change. In this case you do not need special quoting or escaping. The batchfile would look like this (adjust the path of db2cmd to suit your environment).

> ```
> set db2cmd="C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmd.exe"
> @if "%DB2CLP%"=="" %db2cmd% /w /c /i "%0" %* && @goto :EOF
> FOR /F "usebackq skip=3 tokens=4" %%G IN ("aliasname.txt") DO DB2 UNCATALOG DATABASE %%G
> ```

- If you prefer explicit `db2cmd -w -c` prefix on Db2 CLP commands, then you must escape the double-quotes as mentioned by Mark Barinstein's answer, although the %%G is required then inside the script:

  `db2cmd -i -c FOR /F \"usebackq skip=3 tokens=4\" %%G IN ("aliasname.txt") DO DB2 UNCATALOG DATABASE %%G`

-

Additionally, you may need to fix the syntax of the Db2 CLP command e.g. `db2 uncatalog system odbc data source` or alternatively `db2 uncatalog database` depending on what you wish to uncatalog.

Comment: Is there a way where I can check the system to see if my db2cmd is in the Program Files folder or Program Files(x86) Folder and use that to initialize db2cmd?

Comment: You can use `where db2cmd.exe` from cmd. If it is in path it will display. Obviously you can use a for loop to then set the path as a variable.

Comment: HI how can you escape db2cmd.exe without user interference?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `%G` variable reference if you run command from the command line, not `%%G` as you use in batch files.
Double quotes must be escaped.
Try this:

```
db2cmd -i -c FOR /F \"usebackq skip=3 tokens=4\" %G IN (\"aliasname.txt\") DO DB2 UNCATALOG SYSTEM DATABASE %G
```

BTW,
There is no `UNCATALOG SYSTEM DATABASE` DB2 command.
There is `UNCATALOG DATABASE`.